# Proving that $\mathbb{Z}(p)$ is a ring

Tags: ring-theory

Let $p$ be prime. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}(p)= \{a/b\ |\ a,b \text{ are elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(b,p)=1$}\}$ is a ring. (This is called the ring of integers localized at $p$.)

What should be the first step that I should do? Should I show that it is closed under addition, multiplication and inverse since $\mathbb{Z}$ must contain $0$.

Any hint..??

Comment: Yes, check the axioms of a ring, be sure that it is closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: Check the ring axioms, in particular that multiplying and adding fractions of this kind you still get fractions of this kind (here's where $p$ prime is needed)

Comment: This ring is usually denoted $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

Comment: @jmc: that ring $\mathbb Z(p)$ is **never** denoted $\mathbb Z_p$, but is usually denoted $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$. The notation $\mathbb Z_p$ can mean:  1) the  ring  of $p$-adic numbers 2) the ring $\mathbb Z[\frac 1p]$ 3) the field $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, but this  notation is not advisable.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg – Wait; me stupid... You're absolutely right. I didn't even read the question properly.

Comment: Dear @jmc, you are definitely not stupid: only absent-minded, just like a mathematician should be :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg – Right again. After thinking twice, I realise it wasn't that I misread the question (because my answer speaks about a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$). So indeed, something in my brain shortwired, due to, as you say "absent-mindedness". Thanks for correcting me. [By the way, on the notations that you mention: I fully agree that 3) is not advisable. The coincidence of 1) and 2) is unfortunate. I think $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ should always mean 1)...]

Answer (score 3):

I am going to use the notation $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ for $\mathbb{Z}(p)$.

Your definition of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ suggest that you view it as subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the multiplication and addition inherited. This means that you actually should show that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.

This boils down to:

1. Show that $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.
2. Show that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, also $a - b \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.
3. Show that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, also $a \cdot b \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Alternatively, instead of (2.), you can show

- for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, also $a + b \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, and $-a \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want to prove that a set $(R,\cdot, +)$ is a ring, you must prove the same things:

1. $(R,+)$ is an abelian group
2. $\cdot$ is an associative operation
3. For all $a,b,c$ in $R$, the equalities $a\cdot (b+c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c $ and $(a+b)\cdot c = a\cdot c + b\cdot c$ hold.

Comment: Very probably, “ring” in this situation is meant to be unitary as well. So, also show that there is a unit for the multiplication.

Comment: Can u check  this attempt to see if  i did answer the question. Show that it is under additon, multiplicaation and inverse. Since 0 is contain in Z_(p) so o/1=0 so gcd(1,p)=1, thus 0 is in Z_(p).

Comment: @Lynnie — You should use curly braces `{}` instead of parentheses `()` around the $p$. So `\mathbb{Z}_{p}`.